# C++ STL priority queue customer comparator does not work

Tags: c++, comparator, priority-queue

I have written almost similar code in the past and it worked (I remember vaguely). It seems that comparator is not working here?? Any clues?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<queue>
#include<iterator>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

    typedef pair<vector<int>::iterator,vector<int>::iterator> PR;
    struct CompareFn{
        bool operator()(const PR& a, const PR& b){
            //cout<<"a and b first: "<<*(a.first)<<" "<< *(b.first)<<endl;
            return *a.first > *b.first;
        }
    };

vector<int> mergeKSortedArrays(vector<vector<int>> &A) {  
vector<int> result;
    
    priority_queue<PR, vector<PR>, CompareFn> PQ;
    for(auto e:A){  
        if(e.size()>0) PQ.push({e.begin(),e.end()});
    }

    while(PQ.size()>0) {
        PR tmp = PQ.top(); PQ.pop();
        auto cur=tmp.first;
        auto lst=tmp.second;
        result.emplace_back (*cur);
        if((++cur)!=lst) PQ.push({cur,lst});
    }
return result;
}


int main() { 
vector<vector<int>> v= {{2,3,8,10},{1,4,12},{4,5,8}};
 vector<int> result = mergeKSortedArrays(v);
 copy(result.begin(),result.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout," "));
 return 0;
}
```

I was expecting it to work for pair of iterators almost as it works for integers. but it does not.

Comment: How does "_does not work_" manifest itself?

Comment: I am expecting it priority queue to give me numbers.. It is giving me some addresses. It seems like customer comparator is not working correctly. I tried to print a.first and b.first but it prints a.first both times.

Comment: Remembering vaguely that something *almost* similar worked in the past is not a very strong indication of either working or similarity.

Comment: You might want std::merge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `begin()` and `end()` iterators you get from the *copy* of the `vector` in `for(auto e : A)` will be invalid after the iteration ends and the temporary `vector` `e` is destroyed.

Use a reference to the inner `vector` instead:

```
for(auto& e : A) { // "auto& e" makes "e" a reference to the existing vector
    if(e.size()>0) PQ.emplace(e.begin(), e.end());
}
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bjcG3G)

Here's another [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xsdssq) where I've applied the appropriate `const` qualifiers.

Comment: @Const Indeed! I'll fix that! Thanks! (and, nice name btw) Edit: Fixed!

Comment: Yes,... I like `const`. ;)

Comment: Thanks @TedLyngmo, using e by reference fixed the issue !!

Comment: @AlanTuring Glad it did! Cheers!